# how to do a method with a function?

Tags: vb.net, class

How to do a method with extension of function? Here I have a class with a method and a function as an example.

```
class myClass
public sub method()
'some method
end sub

public function func()
'some function
end function

end class
```

And I want to call the method, then the function act as an extension to the method like this:

```
dim x as new myClass
x.method.func
```

How can I do that? I've been looking for this since last night but with no luck. tnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a function is a method.  A `Sub` and a `Function` are both methods.  Secondly, you can't do what you say you want.  It's not that the second method is an extension to the first at all.  It's that the second is called on the result of the first.  For that to be possible, the first has to produce a result, which means that it must be a function.  A `Function` returns something while a `Sub` does not and the second method is called on that return value.  For instance, if you did this:

```
Dim x = y.Method1().Method2()
```

then that is equivalent to this:

```
Dim z = y.Method1()
Dim x = z.Method2()
```

The first is simply a shorthand and is not valid syntax if `Method1` does return an object of the type of which `Method2` is a member.  In your scenario, that's not the case, so stop trying.  Just do this:

```
Dim x As New [myClass]

x.method()
x.func()
```

It's no big deal to split the code over two lines even if you could do it in one.  You can't do it in one, so just do it in two.